# Вывод сообщения в ВКонтакте с помощью Python

Tags: python, бот, вконтакте

Имеется код на Python. Когда пользователь пишет какое-либо слово, бот ему должен выдать "Привет"! Как это сделать в коде?

```
import vk_api 
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType

def main(): 
    vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token='vk1.a.b1Gp3rcbyIwCBke_PXsuU5n56ckYpRpBmbQqb_6drYwSy_PAI1U4C5W4izJv803FpDM-DXyKqoOZdWeHRpgnO7zrxILSWzdqVZALfDU972pnaqrAEyDww4o4p8u8wWOKGkhft567mEXrJZ9YbLrHgNF4TsSmy70cgQpp3u7kQDpdp0E7yBkH3xZ8HvCULtijbdmimKiZb-Ab3K8QWe-Zdw') 
    longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk_session)

    for event in longpoll.listen(): 
        if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.to_me: 
            print("Привет")

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Вместо метода, который пишет пишет в консоль привет

```
print("Привет")
```

Используй метод, который отправляет сообщение пользователю:

```
vk_session.method('messages.send', {'user_id': event.user_id, 'message': 'Привет!'})
```